# Using % is casuing a line break but using px works fine

Tags: css

> li {
>       padding-right: 1%; }

Set in %  causes a line break in ul list, but when changing it into px seems to work fine.

> li {
>       padding-right: 5px; }

What is causing this error? Fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/hsa0r5ym/)

```css
ul,
li {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding-right: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="">CMYK</a>
  <ul>
    <li>FAQ</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Home</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Percentage values are relative to the parent's dimension `right,left concerns the width`

Comment: I know so I reduced the size to 0.5% but does not seem to work.

Comment: Obviously 1% of the parent's width doesn't equal 5px

Comment: How much % value should I use to fit properly? 80px seem to work

Comment: I'm not sure, use the devtools find out the with of the parent and calculate how much is 80px

Comment: the duplicate is not the same situation but explain the same issue of padding with percentage since float and flex item are shrink-to-fit element

Comment: @ZohirSalak any percentage value even 0.0001% will cause a line break because it's percentage and it will get calculated after finding the width of the parent (which is a float element). with pixel we won't have any issue because the pixel will get added to the width of the parent.

Comment: @ZohirSalak since it is a floated element, width does not exist? So it breaks?  Am I correct ?

Comment: @CoDINGinDARK since it's float  element its width depend on the content AND the content is using percentage value so we first find the width using content then the calculated width will be used to find the padding and that padding will be reduced from the width creating the break

Comment: oh wow i never ran into that problem before with percentages, i've always used absolute values for padding and figured it'll be the same, well that you know learn something new everyday, However i meddled with this for a bit, and setting `box-sizing: border-box;` solves it because the padding get swallowed.

Answer (score 1):

`%` always work relative to something. In your case, if you try giving width to your `ul`, you can understand it more clearly. Let's say your `ul` width is *100px*, so the combined with of `li` should be 100px, which means if any `li` goes above *25px* in width, it will break to the next line. See the code below

```css
ul {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding-right: 10%;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="">CMYK</a>
  <ul>
    <li>FAQ</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Home</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: applying the same logic 0.5> should give it padding-right and prevent line-break?

Comment: but, right now I have given 10% and it does not break? Do you mean it breaks at 0.5%?

Comment: it breaks at 0.5% without width specified in my code.

Comment: I have made it 0.5%, please check https://jsfiddle.net/nidhingeorgejoseph/oeaxjwLu/

Comment: you are still defining an explicit width to parent element so you cannot reproduce the issue.